# No file created using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

Below is my program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fstream hd;
    hd.open("fstream.dat", fstream::in | fstream::out);

    hd.put('a');
    hd.close();
    return 0;
}
```

However, no file is created after using executing this program. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Use an `std::ofstream` object.  `std::fstream` won't automatically create a file.

Comment: But what if I need to have a handler that has both read and write ability? @CharlesSalvia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `fstream::app` or `fstream::trunc` flag bit to specify what to do if the file already exists (append or clobber, respectively).

It's a bit idiosyncratic that this also affects whether or not a file is *created*, but C++ inherits this from the C/POSIX `fopen` function.